# Warning: array_replace_recursive(): Expected parameter 2 to be an array,

Tags: magento2, compilation

When I am running this command in the magento 2.4 :
sudo bin/magento s:up && sudo bin/magento s:di:c && sudo bin/magento c:f

I got this error I tied many things but don't work.

Warning: array_replace_recursive(): Expected parameter 2 to be an array, null given in /home/rana/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/Diff/Diff.php on line 146

Comment: what's your php version?

Comment: Finally I got the solution just rename the vendor directory and run sudo composer update.

Comment: PHP version is 7.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just rename the vendor directory and run sudo composer update its work.

Answer (score 3):

You get this error if you have syntax error in your `db_schema_whitelist.json` file.
Just remove it and run:

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist
```

Comment: Okay, I just  just rename the vendor directory and run sudo composer update. Thank you so much!