# Warning: require(vendor/autoload.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in

Tags: magento2, php, theme, composer, server-setup

Below is the error I get in store frontend.

Warning: require(vendor/autoload.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/magento/web/mymagentostorename.com/public_html/poms/libs/phpfastcache_config.php

On running composer update and composer install, I find the installation failure messages for several modules. Could you please share some insights or possible solutions to the issue?

[image]

Comment: This might help you regarding your problem: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/353734/warning-array-replace-recursive-expected-parameter-2-to-be-an-array